# "https://" refers to random site, "http://" is broken, but "http://www" works

Tags: web-hosting, https

I'm running a website which is acting extremely strange.

- At the time of writing, this link works: `http://www.example.com`
- This link doesn't: `http://example.com`
- But it does work if you copy/paste it and run it in Incognito...
- This link (after ignoring a warning) serves a totally unrelated and unknown website: `https://example.com`

I have no idea how to debug this issue. I have contacted the hosting and domain company to investigate the issue. How is the last issue even possible?

Comment: Please add some details as to what web server you're using, if you're using a control panel, and if you have an SSL certificate installed.

Comment: The site uses cPanel, and is running wordpress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://egothieves.com/ redirects to http://www.egothieves.com/. It’s probably a caching issue if it doesn’t work for you (that’s also why it works in private browsing mode for you).

https://www.jevousenprie.com/ seems to be the actual adress of the site that is published at https://egothieves.com/.

Both domains use `ns1.tsohost.co.uk`/`ns2.tsohost.co.uk`/`ns3.tsohost.co.uk` as name servers. Both sites are hosted on the same IP: `188.65.117.68`.

It seems that jevousenprie.com is the only domain using a SSL certificate on this server (or maybe the only one that works). So all 40+ domains used on `188.65.117.68` show this site when accessed via HTTPS:

- https://amplifiacademy.com/
- https://defade.com/
- https://dgcontracts.co.uk/
- https://feelgoodfactorycic.co.uk/
- …

Seems that the server ([SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)?) is misconfigured.

Rob on SO seems to have the very same problem: [Multiple sites per Apache server with SSL showing wrong site with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19070296/1591669) (no answer yet).

Comment: That makes it sound like it's out of our hands. Since we are just a single site on a shared hosting, we will contact the hosting company to fix this.