# SEO issues after HTTPS switch relating to shared IP and SSL (SNI)

Tags: seo, google, ranking

I'm having some trouble getting my site to appear in search rankings.

I ran into the problem when I switched my domain over to ssl/https. The website remained on a shared IP address and since it was the only site on the IP with a certificate all other domains on the shared IP started showing my website if accessed over https.. as a result Google has indexed lots of my pages on other domains.

This is called SNI (Server Name Indication), which allows you to install multiple SSL's on a single IP. What happens is, since the domains are sharing that IP and only one has an SSL installed, when the server receives a request it defaults to the primary SSL installed.

I've tried several things to correct the situation:

- Moved my domain to it's own dedicated IP address
- Installed SSL certificates on the other domains effecting my rankings so now when pages are accessed over https, it shows the source site, rather than my site.
- Setup 302 redirects on any pages on the sites redirecting to my own so if a page is accessed from the 3rd party domains it redirects to the correct page on my domain.

.. however, it's been several weeks and i'm not seeing any improvement. My site is in Google Search Console and I have set preferred domain and forced Google to re-index my site.

I know Google is listing my pages because if I search for `site:mydomain.com` I can see all indexed pages.

I've also asked Google to re-index the other sites affecting my site.

I can also bring up certain pages if I search for its `<title>` in it's entirety... However just searching for the company name it's bringing up my pages as if they're on the other domains on the shared IP.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? I'd hazard a guess that the other domains are ranking my pages and since they have more authority than my domain Google is choosing to show them in search results instead.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: Not exactly, i've committed SEO suicide and want to know how I can fix it, everything I am trying is not working. Google is seeing my site as duplicate content and omitting it from results.

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you have done a lot of the right things. I would recommend changing the 302 redirects to 301. It will take more than a couple of weeks for this to straighten out. If your site is not too big, then, if you do not abuse the feature, you can use the Google Search Console's Fetch as Google and Submit to Index. There is a limit for each day. Do enough important pages each day. Also, remember that this option still takes days. Do not expect an immediate result. It will not change until the googlebot comes back in 1-2 days. Otherwise, you can wait. It will take a while.

Comment: Related (from the other perspective): [“https://” refers to random site, “http://” is broken, but “http://www” works](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/55685/17633) · [HTTPS and HTTP URLs point to different places?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/60385/17633)