# HTTPS of my own website hijacked by someone else?

Tags: https, godaddy

My site creativeblends(dot)tv as of right now has only a coming soon message, nothing more. The other day I sent someone the link with www in front and when opening (in Firefox) it opened automatically the secure protocol version of it.

The weird thing is, I don't have any secure protocol at all. I bought the domain from Godaddy and have my site(s) hosted there too (yes, it happens with more than just one site). But I don't need a SSL because I don't manage any kind of personal or private information.

The problem:
When I accept to make an exception for the https version it opens my domain (the very same but with https in front) but with a completely other page content from iwant-glameyes(dot)com

The funny thing is, that iwant-glameyes(dot)com bought the SSL from Godaddy themselves. Did they hack me? Is GoDaddy involved somehow?

How do they manage:
a) use my domain?
b) use my host IP?
c) without redirecting and hosting content on my server show their page?

And more important:
How can I get rid of this problem?

Edit:
This question: ["https://" refers to random site, "http://" is broken, but "http://www" works](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55685/https-refers-to-random-site-http-is-broken-but-http-www-works/92493#92493) seems to be similar, but unfortunately nobody could give a real solution.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? (likely) If so, this is just another site on the same server.

Comment: Not sure where to look that up but I suppose with GoDaddy there are hundred of thousands of sites on the same server.

Comment: If you are not paying for dedicated server or something similar, then that is what is happening. The server is not recognizing the request as being a site on the server and (assuming Apache) just returning the first site created. Your complaint is not uncommon. If you purchase a certificate and install it, assuming you can without a package upgrade, then it should all work okay.

Comment: So this is common? I really don't understand how someone else can have access to my domain. This shouldn't be happening at all. With or without a certificate. Why in any common sense should another page appear on my domain just because of a certificate? I tried to google it but can't find that this is a common issue. Are you sure we are talking about the same thing here?

Comment: They do not have access to your domain. You are safe there. It is just an effect of a HTTP request coming to a server that does not have the site defined. This same effect can happen for HTTPS requests when the site in question does not have a certificate. This happens when HTTP and HTTPS protocols are both answered by the same server. As a previous web host, I never allowed mixed protocols. Yes. This is rather common. Chrome, the browser, does not allow HTTPS requests for sites that do have a certificate. I do not know about IE and Firefox.

Comment: The third-party is hosted on the same IP address as you, which occurs with shared hosting accounts. They have an SSL assigned to that IP address too. If viewed in an HTTPS viewer, your site has a `302` (temporary) redirect back to itself. Firefox is resolving that to the shared IP address with port 443, which pulls up the third-party site. In short, this is a server configuration issue you should speak with GoDaddy's Hosting department about. The third-party, or you, should be on separate IP addresses, and until you obtain an SSL, you should redirect any requests for HTTPS URLs to HTTP.

Comment: "when opening (in Firefox) it opened automatically the secure protocol version" - Are _you_ seeing this as well? Or just the "someone" you shared the link with? (Just wondering how that is relevant to the story?) And what kind of _redirect_ is it? Is the browser switching to HTTPS from the get go (ie. Firefox thinks this domain is HTTPS only?), you see a 3xx redirect in the network traffic, or perhaps the DNS is directing you somewhere else?

Comment: @DocRoot: I sent the link: www.creativeblends.tv through whatsapp to a colleague and when I checked the link on my side it opened Firefox but automatically with the https in front.

Comment: @dan: I already talked to Godaddy but all they said is: buy a SSL protocol because there is nothing else that we can do. But I'm really not interested in spending more money, much less in something I really don't need. I simply can't believe that something like that can happen. There must be an option like you say to redirect https to http or something else that does not mix up different sites or show a site on someones else domain.

Comment: This really seems like a GoDaddy issue and their answer to your request is somewhat pathetic. Furthermore in order to use an SSL certificate you would need a dedicated IP address (yes SNI is a thing but is not compatible with old browser) and the fact that GoDaddy is setup in a way where their shared addresses can return an answer to a :443 SSL request I don't think should be a thing. In my opinion no response for an HTTPS requests is better then an unexpected different response if you have not specifically set your site to use SSL.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. A no response would be enough and make me happy. But that my domain returns an answer with a different content is just not acceptable.

Comment: Not the answer you want but unfortunately there would be nothing you could actually do on your own since this is the server responding to HTTPS requests on the IP you are using. DNS is oblivious to ports so you would be unable to stop your domain from loading HTTPS and script changes are too far down the line since this is happening before your content is actually loaded.

Comment: Yep. The second one seems to be the exact same problem, unfortunately no solution was provided. Do I have to route port 443 different somehow? Any ideas?

Comment: Since your on shared hosting you can't, you have no control over the actual web server (apache) config. This also means you can't do anything about denying access to certain ports since this is also a lower level configurations which isn't granted to shared hosted users since those settings would effect all sites being hosted on that server. If GoDaddy isn't helping then your choices would be change to another shared provider or purchase a cheap VPS and setup everything to your exact needs.

Comment: @Christoph You can redirect all HTTPS to HTTP URLs as I wrote and that would resolve this. It looks like you're using cPanel, so look for _Redirects_ under _Domains_ in your cPanel account. Or, you can upload a .htaccess file to the root directory. You can also ask for the account to be re-provisioned to another server, or ask for a refund and host your site elsewhere. Asking for level 2 support might help with both.

Comment: Thanks dan, I will try to talk to GoDaddy again. And yes, I use cPanel. Is the Redirects under Domains any different than the .htaccess file? Because I already tried with the .htaccess file but since the SSL comes before any other access the .htaccess file is never read which basically makes this useless in my case.

Comment: GoDaddy's Redirects under Domains doesn't have an option to redirect https to http, unfortunately.